# How filter NSPredicate when passing data between view controllers

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

Tapping on a collectionView cell should pass only the filtered attribute from an NSFetchRequest, but is instead passing every object to the next viewController, itself a tableViewController

Filtering by attribute

```
var album: Album?

    func fetchAlbumDetailResults() -> NSFetchedResultsController<Album> {
        guard let producer = album?.producer else { return fetchAlbumDetailResults() }

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Album> = Album.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [
            NSSortDescriptor(key: "producer", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))
        ]
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "producer == %@", producer)

        let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
                                             managedObjectContext: mainContext,
                                             sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
                                             cacheName: nil)
        return frc
    }
```

Expected Results: fetch only albums produced by a single producer

Actual Results:  fetches every album

Comment: If there is one producer why do you sort with it?

Comment: Is the fetch request executed or is `fetchCollectionResults()` returned?

Comment: @E.Coms There will presumably be many producers.

Comment: @Willeke yes. The fetch request is executed but returns every album produced instead of the ones created by a producer.

Comment: What the producer class? A string or an array?

Comment: You may not need the sort as you want to get one specific producer

Comment: The sort will inquire many producers

Comment: How do you use the result of `fetchAlbumDetailResults`? Is `fetchAlbumDetailResults` recursive?

Comment: @E.Coms The struct is called `Album` and has a variable named `producer`. I tried not using the sort function and just the predicate. No dice.

Comment: What do you mean **is `fetchAlbumDetailResults` recursive**? It is a lazy var on my tableview controller class.

Comment: Objective: tap on an album among a list of albums in my collection view. Each album has a producer. If more than one album is created by the producer, pass a list of all the producer's albums to the detail view, itself a tableview controller class with a list of said producer's albums.

Comment: Did you print ‘producer’ and show us the results?

Comment: Did you try “produce = %@“

Comment: @E.Coms single equals `=` has no effect